# Should I not post and answer my own question about a general programing concept?

Tags: discussion

I posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609676/how-can-an-async-method-run-synchronously?noredirect=1#comment117749976_66609676

While I was writing the question, I looked into the docs and found the answer, so I decided to answer my own question. Within 30 seconds of posting (so there is no way they had time to read it), someone downvoted both my answer and the question and left a comment (which was removed) saying it was "irrelevant". The downvotes were then removed (I think) but the question received a vote to close for a "Community Specific Reason".

I could understand a vote if it was a duplicate maybe. Should I not have posted this question?

Comment: The first close vote was for not being reproducible or being caused by a typo, specifically. (Can’t comment on it, though.)

Comment: If it was closed due the issue being due to a typo that would be a legitimate close vote (IMO) regardless if a downvote was issue or a comment was submitted, reported, and deleted by a moderator.  The (downvote and close vote) have nothing to do with the comment

Comment: That question has been asked probably hundreds of times at this point on SO (and elsewhere).  There's nothing new or useful that question is adding that's not already covered much better in lots of places...That said, there's no reason to post on meta every time you get a single downvote or close vote on one of your questions.  If you don't think a question should be closed you should really wait until the question is *actually closed* before posting on meta to dispute it.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the duplicates. I removed my post. (There wasn't a typo though: it runs exactly how I described it would). I mostly just felt like the flag given was incorrect, but I guess that's what the review process is for. I spent a lot of time researching it, so I kinda hoped it would be helpful. I'll post my answer under an existing question if I think it adds anything.

Comment: Follow up: if I believe I have something to add about a topic, is it ever appropriate to create a new question even a similar one exists? Say someone asks about A which is made possible by B, so I ask about B directly. Should I always find questions about A to talk about B?

Comment: @ConnorLow deleting questions is a bad thing and should be avoided. That can lead to a question ban.

Comment: @10Rep Deleting a good question that's useful is a bad thing.  Deleting a bad question that's not useful is not.  You don't get post banned for a single bad question, you get post banned for a pattern of bad behavior, and the solution to avoiding it is to make a good faith effort to post quality content, not to avoid deleting content when you make a mistake.

Comment: @10Rep AFAIK, deleting itself doesn’t lead to a question ban; it just makes it harder to get out of one, should one get banned in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After sleeping on it, I realize I was being a whiny little punk here on meta, so sorry about that.

I should have assumed the question had been asked before since it was a pretty common topic; then, I should have sought out one of those questions to give my answer there. Even then, I should make sure I could provide additional value to the discussion.

Comment: Don't knock yourself too hard, compared to others your meta post was and is pretty level. We're all human, sometimes we knee-jerk before we give it time to hang and dry :)